# Where in the database is the Date Added for Group records?

Tags: groups

I'm trying to help a friend. A slew of his contact records got added to groups that they don't belong in. It happened on July 19th. I thought the civicrm_group_contact table would have a timestamp column, but I don't see one. Where is this Date Added stored (see below)? Is there a way to select these group records and delete them? Thanks...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That information is contained in the table civicrm_subscription_history

To remove them from those regular groups you would need to remove them from both the civicrm_subscription_history table and the civicrm_group_contact table

Seamus

Comment: but nothing via the UI or an extension eh?